# Delphi: Return value might be undefined, despite setting it after begin

Tags: delphi, delphi-5

can anyone tell me why I get "Return value ... might be undefined" here:

```
function TXMLAcceptorBCOLSubmission.createRecordsInBCFEEPAR(AXML: TRipXMLElement): String;
var
  ...
begin
  Result := '';
```

Comment: Could you show the complete code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am using Delphi 5 and it looks like the problem is caused by declaring more than 30 variables (I know, I know). It doesn't seem to matter what they are called or what types they are.

Comment: Indeed; this was a bug that has been resolved in Delphi 2009: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=51078

Comment: That fits with my experience. There seems to be a certain number of variables the compiler will "track" for the assignedness check, and `Result` is frequently the first to be abandoned. The workaround is simple: Write shorter functions.

Comment: Report 51078 says that it was fixed in 12.0.2872.27234, but I'm pretty sure that I saw it in D2010.

Answer (score 2):

Following code doesn't generate a warning using Delphi 5 so

- either it is a *bug* in an other Delphi version (you should mention the version you use)
- or either it is something you didn't show us yet.

**Code**

```
program ProveAPoint;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
uses SysUtils;

type
  TRipXMLElement = record
  end;
  TXMLAcceptorBCOLSubmission = class
  public
    function createRecordsInBCFEEPAR(AXML: TRipXMLElement): string;
  end;

function TXMLAcceptorBCOLSubmission.createRecordsInBCFEEPAR(AXML: TRipXMLElement): String;
begin
  Result := '';
end;

var
  AXML: TRipXMLElement;
begin
  with TXMLAcceptorBCOLSubmission.Create do
  begin
     createRecordsInBCFEEPAR(AXML);
     Free;
  end;
end.
```